# How to change binding in zsh? command key vs control key

Tags: terminal, keybindings, zsh

I moved to Mac OS and I'm facing the control vs command key problem.

I already changed the settings for my external keyboard, so that my control key is mapped to command key and viceversa. This fixes my habits of ctrl-x,c,v,z and ctrl-t,ctrl-w for the browser and most applications.

However, when I work with Terminal and zsh, now ctrl-w, ctrl-u, ctrl-a etc... does not do what I expect, because I'm of course sending command-w etc.

How do I fix this once and for all so that I don't need to change my habits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by switching from the default Mac OS terminal to [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com)

which allows to remap modifiers very easily.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the awesome, free [**Karabiner-Elements** app](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org).
2. Install the ["Keyboard shortcuts for Terminal apps" mod](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=terminal#terminal_navi).

Then, instead of using `^W`, `^U`, `^A`, etc., you can just use the modifier keys (<kbd>⌘</kbd>/<kbd>⌥</kbd>/<kbd>⌃</kbd>) plus the arrow/delete keys (<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>⌫</kbd>/<kbd>⌦</kbd>), just as you do in the rest of macOS.

Don't like those exact mappings? Just `git clone https://github.com/pqrs-org/KE-complex_modifications.git` and write your own mod.